# mvc 3 membership Role.AddUserToRole

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, roles

i have array for role selected. and now i want to add that array role to specified user. i have a controller like this :

```
string[] array = collection["RolesSelected"].Split(',');
        try
        {
            Roles.AddUserToRoles(username, array);

        }
```

but when i submit, nothing happens. when i debug in

```
 Roles.AddUserToRoles(username, array);
```

it shows correct. i mean username is correct, and array is correct(list of role that checked).

if i try to remove role,

```
Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles(username,array)
```

the role for username is removed.

why did i can remove role but i cant add role ?

thanks

ps:sorry for my english :)

### EDIT

i can remove role for specified user using

```
Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles(username,array)
```

but i cant add role to specified  user.
when i remove all roles from specified user, then i can add role for user. 
should i remove all roles first, and then adding them again (i think i cant do that because i have many users and roles for my project)

Comment: Post the your roles array and (if you write it) the code for AddUserToRoles. Maybe the roles are not in the roles tables?

Comment: thanks iridigo, i use Roles.AddUserToRoles(username, array) for adding roles to specified user. i can get my array list. i can remove role for user using the same array, Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles(username, array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are encountering an error (`System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException` is being thrown) by trying to add a user to a role in which s/he already exists.  Try this instead:

```
string[] array = collection["RolesSelected"].Split(',');
foreach (string role in array)
{
   if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(username, role))
   {
      Roles.AddUserToRole(username, role);
   }
}
```

That said, if you want the user to *only* have the roles specified in the array, you'd want to remove all the roles first and then do the `AddUserToRole` call.